# La « puce-système » et le « système sur puce » : fréquence et adéquation ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, informatique, fréquence-utilisation

Comme traduction de [*system on (a) chip* (SoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip), on trouve principalement [*système sur puce*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370194) (GDT) et [*puce-système*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=system%20on%20chip&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) (FranceTerme) pour le « circuit intégré sur une puce qui contient l'ensemble des composants nécessaires à la mise en œuvre des fonctions d'un système » (FranceTerme). On trouve aussi l'ajout du terme [*multiprocesseur/multicoeur*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502479) dans certains cas.

Hormis le mot en anglais, quel serait le terme le plus fréquemment employé en français ? Entre *puce-système* ou *système sur puce* pourquoi trouverait-on l'un plus adéquat et lequel s'incrirait le mieux dans le lexique existant (*système sur.../puce-...*) ; est-ce davantage un *système* qu'une *puce* ou finalement ni l'un ni l'autre et peut-on faire mieux ?

Answer (score 2):

Dans la vie courante (des quelques praticiens du domaine¹), on écrit « SoC » et on prononce [sɔk].

Comme tu as trouvé, le [gouvernement français](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=system%20on%20chip&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) spécifie « puce-système ». Mais [ce n'est pas très utilisé](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22puce-syst%C3%A8me%22+site%3Afr). J'ai l'impression que [« système sur puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+puce%22&site%3Afr) et [« système sur une puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+une+puce%22&site%3Afr) sont beaucoup plus courants. (Je ne me base pas sur le nombre de résultats estimé par Google : ce nombre est très peu fiable, et ne peut pas servir de base de comparaison entre des termes qui n'ont pas le même nombre de mots. Mais en faisant une estimation visuelle de la diversité des premiers résultats pour ces trois termes, je pense que « système sur une puce » est plus courant que « système sur puce » qui est lui-même plus courant que « puce-système ».)

Le titre de l'[article de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syst%C3%A8me_sur_une_puce) est « système sur une puce », ce qui a certainement influencé beaucoup de gens. Ce titre ne semble pas refléter d'une concertation particulière : il n'y a aucune [discussion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:Syst%C3%A8me_sur_une_puce). L'article a été renommé de [« System-on-a-chip »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=System-on-a-chip&action=history) en [« Système sur puce »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Syst%C3%A8me_sur_puce&action=history) le 31 octobre 2012, puis en « Système sur une puce » le 20 mars 2013.

Le magazine [*L'Usine nouvelle*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Usine_nouvelle) a utilisé [« système sur puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+puce%22) dans 25 articles et [« systèmes sur puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+puce%22) dans 37, soit un total de 60 puisque [2 articles sont comptés deux fois](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+puce%22+%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+puce%22). C'est plus que [« système sur une puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+une+puce%22) et [« systèmes sur une puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22syst%C3%A8me+sur+une+puce%22) dans 2+8, et [« puce-système »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22puce-syst%C3%A8me%22) dans aucun, et à peu près autant que 38+28 pour [« system-on-chip »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22system-on-chip%22) (avec ou sans traits d'union) et [« system-on-a-chip »](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ausinenouvelle.com+%22system-on-a-chip%22). [STMicroelectronics](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/STMicroelectronics), qui est je pense l'acteur le plus gros du domaine en France, a [publié plusieurs communiqués](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ast.com+%22puce-syst%C3%A8me%22) utilisant « système(s) sur puce » et aucun avec « puce-système ».

La formulation « système sur une puce » pose un problème quand on veut la mettre au pluriel. Il y a plusieurs systèmes, chacun sur sa puce : faut-il parler de [« systèmes sur des puces »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+des+puces%22&oq=%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+des+puces%22) ? Non, ce n'est visiblement pas une expression consacrée. Le pluriel consacré est [« systèmes sur une puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+des+puces%22&oq=%22syst%C3%A8mes+sur+une+puces%22), mais il donne l'impression qu'on combine plusieurs systèmes sur une même puce. « Systèmes sur puce » ne pose pas ce problème : chaque système est « sur puce », sans implication que tous sont sur la même. « Puces-systèmes » ne pose pas non plus ce problème.

Le concept principal est le *système*, pas la puce : il est caractérisé par le fait qu'un *système* constitué par plusieurs processeurs (au sens large) est physiquement rassemblé sur une seule puce. Il serait donc plus logique de parler de *système-puce* que de *puce-système*, mais visiblement [« système-puce »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22syst%C3%A8me-puce%22) n'est pas usité.

Je trouve que l'adjectif *intégré* correspondrait bien au concept. Mais comme c'est un degré d'intégration par dessus le *circuit intégré*, cet adjectif est hors de course.

Ma préférence va donc à « système sur puce ». Mais en pratique, quelque choix qu'on fasse, si on veut être compris, on ajoute l'explication « (*system-on-chip*) ».

¹  <sub>Source : expérience personnelle (j'écris des logiciels pour ce genre de bestioles).</sub>

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie Tous les processeurs de smartphone sont des SoC, ce n'est pas une nouveauté ! La portée exacte est variable : pendant longtemps les smartphones avaient en général 4 composants (SoC, modem, mémoire vive, mémoire de masse), mais de nos jours le modem est en général intégré, et la mémoire de masse souvent « collée » à la puce principale. Sur un PC récent, le « processeur principal » intègre pas mal de périphériques ; si on ne parle pas de SoC, c'est plutôt par tradition et pour une raison commerciale (c'est une conception 100% Intel/AMD et pas un amalgame).

Comment: Oui ARM etc., je comprends. La portée, comme tu l'expliques. Je sais pas si c'est la portée de la systématisation ou la portée de l'intégration mais c'est certainement la notion qui permet d'articuler l'intensité de la chose. J'aime pas beaucoup Apple mais j'ai certainement été influencé par leur présentation où on essaye de se démarquer commercialement à défaut de technologiquement peut-être. Mais si on intègre un truc comme une fonction pour des codecs, ou un morceau d'un OS en particulier, est-ce que ça change ce dont on parle, ou c'est simplement _propriétaire_. Merci pour la perspective.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai l'impression que c'est l'abréviation anglaise *SoC* que l'on rencontre le plus en France. Le mot *puce* (pour *chip*) est couramment employé mais c'est surtout dans un contexte de vulgarisation. On tend souvent à éviter les termes courants qui ne font pas assez "sérieux".

Je trouve pas mal de *système sur puce*, moins de *puce-système* mais ce n'est pas ce que je choisirais.

S'il me fallait trouver quelque chose de bien français, mon choix irait peut-être à *système tout-en-un* ou *microprocesseur tout-en-un*.

Multiprocesseur ou multicœur seraient incorrects techniquement parlant.

Comment: Je trouve que _système tout-en-un_ me fait penser à _all in one_ en anglais ou à une pub, mais _microprocesseur tout-en-un_, vraiment bien. Mais pourquoi ne pas remonter en amont, en spéculant que ce genre de système va devenir la norme, avec _système imprimé_ et _processeur unifié/autonome_ voire _métro-processeur_ hahaha ? Curiosité, quand en France disons les gens disent « SoC » c'est prononcé comme en français ? Merci !

Comment: Oui, comme un soc, l'un des rares mots français aux racines gauloises.

Comment: L'excellent « chaussure de la charrue », merci je connaissais pas ce mot-là !